# SQL command to INSERT a row - but when current_timestamp() exists, update it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL table like this

```
| id (int) | price (float) | date (current_timestamp)|
|----------|---------------|-------------------------| 
| 1        | 5.50          | 2021-09-04              |
| 2        | 20.49         | 2021-09-05              |
```

I need help with SQL command for update row  `WHERE date = CURDATE()` but only **if row with *today timestamp* exists**. If not then insert. How?

Comment: Research: INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE. You may need to make sure that `date` is defined as unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `on duplicate key update` . . . assuming you have a unique index or constraint on id.

```
insert into t (id, price, date)
    values (?, ?, ?)
    on duplicate key update date = values(date);
```

If `id` is not the primary key or declared unique, you can add the constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_id unique (id);
```

Comment: I added unique index on date and that works. Thanks.